# Is eliminating construction of unused object allowed in standard even if constructor has observable side-effects?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, elision

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct M {
    M() { std::cout << "M\n"; }
};

template <class T>
struct Test {
    Test() { std::cout << "Test\n"; }
    inline static auto m = M{};
};
int main() {
    Test<int> t1;
    //Test t;
    //(void)&t1.m;
}
```

Using the latest [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uvyYo5pFxwX1dIes) or [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/m9NfEnkcznSX9Vz6) the only "Test" is printed out. But if we [use an address](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lLM2R1gAiFYDlpa7) of `m` object (uncomment the last line `(void)&t1.m;`) or transform `Test` class template into the [regular (non-templated) class](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MLQ9NJIP4CtFDJVA) then the `M` constructor was called.

Is this behaviour allowed by the C++ standard? Any quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's spelled out in the standard.

> **[temp.inst]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#4) Unless a member of a class template or a member template is a
> declared specialization, the specialization of the member is
> implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a
> context that requires the member definition to exist or if the
> existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the
> program; **in particular, the initialization (and any associated side
> effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data
> member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the
> static data member to exist**.

Since your example doesn't use the static data member at all, its definition is never fully instantiated.

Comment: And from the previous clause regarding that definitions will not be instantiated as part of implicit instantiation, [\[temp.inst\]/3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.inst#3.1), _"The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of the definitions**, of [...] static data members"_. This may be relevant as an explicit instantiation definition _will_ lead to the definition of the static data member(s) of that instantiation.

Comment: @dfri - The OP did not use an explicit instantiation definition. That would be a subject for another question.

Comment: Do you know any background why instantiation of static data member of templates is optional versus for regular class? Maybe a link to existing question on SO?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Imho it's possibly interesting/relevant _context_, but this is purely opinion-based, hence my _"This may be relevant"_ (surely no need to include it in an answer to the post, but readers of the post _may_ not know of these subtle details).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - It's not just static data members. It's all members subject to the ODR. And this done in the interest of savings. Don't pay what you don't use (as a library user).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - BTW, if you want to force it, adding an ODR-use of the static variable in the constructor of `Test<>` should do it.

Comment: I understand about conception "don't pay for unused things" but how does this correlate with regular class? The member is still unused for non-templated class, but ... always instantiated.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - No, not instantiated. It's **defined**. The inline is a red-herring here. We are talking about rules that predate that. For non-templates, you'd orignally declare the static member in the class and then add a definition in some TU. That definition incurs initialization. Templates don't instantiate definitions unless they really need them, as a matter of design.